# Trying to get underline to start relative to the nav menu item in SCSS

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to implement a menu nav bar that on hover highlights the menu item with an underline animation from LEFT to RIGHT.

Currently I have the underline animating from the center of the menu item to the outside.

I have tried searchng for a solution to this but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here is a link to the project on codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JowgqP

HTML

```
<menu>
  <p><a href="http://factmag.com/tag/kanye-west" target="_blank"><strong>Home</strong></a> 
  <a href="http://factmag.com/tag/jay-z" target="_blank"><strong>About</strong></a>
  <a href="http://factmag.com/tag/g-o-o-d-music" target="_blank"><strong>Portfolio</strong></a> 
    <a href="http://www.factmag.com/2015/02/12/kanye-west-premieres-wolves-featuring-sia-vic-mensa-produced-cashmere-cat-sinjin-hawke/" target="_blank"><strong>Contact</strong></a> <strong>

  <p class="note">This is a recreation of the link hover effect from <a href="http://www.factmag.com/2015/02/13/kanye-west-pusha-t-2-chainz-perform-first-annual-roc-city-classic-watch-full-show/">factmag.com</a></small>
</menu>
```

CSS (SCSS)

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Serif:400,700,400italic);

$link-color: #E71818;
$text-color: black;
$article-font: Noto serif, serif;

menu {
  color: $text-color;
  font-family: $article-font;
  max-width: 30em;
}
p {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
menu a {
  @extend %fancy-link;
}
.note {
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 1px solid $link-color;
  color: #777;
  font-size: .8em;
  font-style: italic;
  margin-top: 2em;
  padding-top: 1em;
}
%fancy-link {
  color: $link-color;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-out;
  &:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0;
    background: #f00;
    visibility: hidden;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  }
  &:hover {
    transition: all 0.15s ease-out;
    &:before {
        visibility: visible;
        transform: scaleX(1);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default transformation point is `center center`...or rather `50% 50%` for ease of reference. (For 2 dimensions...we'll leave out z offsets for now.)

You would have to amend this so that the origin is now `center left`

```
 &:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0;
    background: #f00;
    visibility: hidden;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transform-origin: center left; /* here */
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    }
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/yyZBpW)

[**Transform-Origin @ MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)